# returning map of employeeName and average salary of all his managers in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have been trying to find out some way to "return average salary of all the managers of an employee mapped with employee Name for a given employeeList ". I have achieved this is java 7 .However I am unable to achieve this is java 8.
Below is my Manager class,Employee class and method "Map<String,Double>  getAverageSalary" .Please help me to do this in java 8.

```
    public class Manager {
        private String name;
    private double salary;
    
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    }

**Employee class and the method** :

    public class Employee {
    private String eName;
        private List<Manager> managers;
        public String geteName() {
            return eName;
        }
        public void seteName(String eName) {
            this.eName = eName;
        }
        public List<Manager> getManagers() {
            return managers;
        }
        public void setManagers(List<Manager> managers) {
            this.managers = managers;
        }
        
        public Map<String,Double>  getAverageSalary(List<Employee> empList){
            double sum=0.0;
            double avg=0.0;
            Map<String ,Double> avaerageSalary=new HashMap<String,Double>();
            for(Employee emp:empList) {
                
                for(Manager mg:emp.getManagers()) {
                    sum=sum+mg.getSalary();
                }
                avg=sum/emp.getManagers().size();
                avaerageSalary.put(emp.eName, avg);
            }
            
            
            return avaerageSalary;
        }
        
    }

Also suggest me good sources to become proficient in java 8 syntax.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream over your `empList` collect them to map using `Employee::getEName` as a key extractor and by mapping the stream of `managers` list of each employee mapping to double using `Manager::getSalary` and getting the average:

```
public Map<String,Double>  getAverageSalary(List<Employee> empList){           
    return empList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       Employee::getEName, 
                       emp -> emp.getManagers()
                                 .stream()
                                 .mapToDouble(Manager::getSalary)
                                 .average().getAsDouble()));
}
```

Comment: Hi Eritrean it works! thanks . Can you please suggest me some resources which can me proficient in java 8 syntax and its usage .I have been working on java 7 earlier Recently i have started working on java 8 .Its much needed for my job please help me Eritrean

Comment: there are many resources on the net, books for different levels, tutorials, youtube videos, paid online courses ... i can't tell you the one that is suitable for you. Try everything depending on what you are working on. What is always worth a look is the [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/?s=java+8) or [mkyong](https://mkyong.com/tutorials/java-8-tutorials/). And at [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/modern-java-learn-java-8-features-by-coding-it/) regularly offered courses that are relatively cheap (around 15€).

Comment: And if you have a specific question and can't get anywhere with your own research, you can ask your question here on StackOverflow. Usually you will get quick feedback provided your question follows these guidelines [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment with Java 8 Streams. One possible solution will be something like this:
Employee gets a new method for calculating the averageSalary of it's manager. Based on that the list of Employees can be transformed to a map

```
 public class Employee {

...
      Double getAverageManagerSalary() {
        return managers.stream()
                .mapToDouble(manager -> manager.getSalary())
                .average()
                .getAsDouble();
    }

    public Map<String,Double> getAverageSalary(List<Employee> empList){
        return empList.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Employee::geteName, 
                                Employee::getAverageManagerSalary)
                );
    }           
}
```

Comment: Hi David,what you told is creating a method which calculates average of salary of all managers.  My question says find out average salary for all managers of an employee.

Comment: Hi @alok2678
I updated my comment, the method was meant for the Employee class.